# How to change polyline color in google map by ajax call?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have multiple PolyLine in my google map based on php variables :

```
var line<?= $connection->id ?> = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [
        new google.maps.LatLng(<?= $startLat ?>, <?= $startLng ?>), 
        new google.maps.LatLng(<?= $endLat ?>, <?= $endLng ?>)
    ],
    strokeColor: worker(),
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 6,
    map: map
});
```

I should change my `strokeColor` value by Ajax call like this:

```
(function worker() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/datacenter-connection/check?id=<?= $connection->id ?>', 
        success: function(data) {
            return data;
        },
        complete: function() {
        // Schedule the next request when the current one's complete
            setTimeout(worker, 5000);
        }
    });
})();
```

My php controller function will return "red" or "green" value.

How should I refresh `strokeColor` value (each interval) by Ajax call of this function?

Answer (score 0):

You could use  setOptions eg:

```
  line.setOptions({strokeColor: worker()});
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: worker is not defined! Should I put worker function inside my initMap()?

Comment: obviously  .. you should place the worker() function at a porper scoping level ..